# Get active Host and Port from jdbc connection to oracle server (don't parse url)

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

is there a way to get connected host and port of a JDBC connection to a Oracle DB Server?

I know, i could parse the URL. But we use failover and i want to know, which server i'm actually connected with. Parsing of URLs is static and error prone because of the different formats we us.

Couldn't find it in the connection metadata.

With 'select * from global_name' i could get the servicename. But i haven't found a way to get the host and port, we are connected to.

Any idea?

Comment: Why do you need to know which host the application is connected to? What use case are you trying to satisfy?

Comment: We have several application servers which can connect to several db servers. The applications servers are reachable via different URL's. If we find an error we need an easy way to know on which combination we are looking at (combination of app server and db server). To accomplish this, we want to show application server and db server on our web gui. For failover tests it would be nice to know, which db server we are actually connected to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about the port (which is really the port on the listener), but for host you might try:

```
select utl_inaddr.get_host_name, utl_inaddr.get_host_address from dual;
```

There are other options on db side (such as querying v$instance), see [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/identifying-host-names-and-addresses.php).  For example, the SID you might use:

```
select sys_context('userenv','instance_name') from dual;
```

Hope that helps.  Also note that I use utl_inaddr, but only for logging and email/alerting purposes.

EDIT:

Also, be aware that there are some concerns with spoofing Oracle session info, partly why I noted that I only use this to add context to alerts and logs.  I don't pretend to know all the ins/outs, but basically this issue concerns a client pretending to be someone (or from somewhere) else.  Since you're controlling the connection via your java app, it shouldn't be a concern, but see [here](http://www.integrigy.com/security-resources/analysis/Integrigy_Spoofing_Oracle_Session_Information.pdf) for more if you care.

Comment: Thx for the security hint! We are thinking about password protecting this information. Only logged in users with suitable rights will see this information.

Comment: You will need to have your DBA set up ACLs set up to run the above queries in Oracle 11g to avoid the following ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_INADDR", line 4
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_INADDR", line 35 see http://www.smartmarmot.com/2011/10/error-ora-24247-network-access-denied-by-access-control-list-acl-and-ora-06512-on-orabbix/

Answer (score 3):

here are some info you can get from a Connection:

```
            Connection dbConnection = null;
        try {
            dbConnection = dataSource.getConnection();
            DatabaseMetaData dbMetaData = dbConnection.getMetaData();
            getLogger().debug("DB Product Name   = " + dbMetaData.getDatabaseProductName());
            getLogger().debug("DB Product Version= " + dbMetaData.getDatabaseProductVersion());
            getLogger().debug("DB Driver Name    = " + dbMetaData.getDriverName());
            getLogger().debug("DB Driver Version = " + dbMetaData.getDriverVersion());
            getLogger().debug("DB Username         = " + dbMetaData.getUserName());
            getLogger().debug("DB URL            = " + dbMetaData.getURL());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            getLogger().debug("Failed to recover DatabaseMetaData: "+e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {
            if (dbConnection != null) {
                try {
                    dbConnection.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    getLogger().error("Failed to close the DB connection: "+ex.getMessage(), ex);
                }
            }
        }
```

Check the DatabaseMetaData if you need more/different info.
Example of output:

```
DB Product Name   = Oracle
DB Product Version= Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Data Mining
and Real Application Testing options
DB Driver Name    = Oracle JDBC driver
DB Driver Version = 11.2.0.2.0
DB Schema         = XXXXX
DB URL            = jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:11010:MYSID
```

Comment: thx for the answer. But it's not the information i need. I need the host, port and sid we are actually connected to.

Comment: i have edited my post with an example of output. if you want to get the individual component for the url you probably will have to parse it, since i don't think the elements are available individually but either way, it's easy: search for the char "@" and then split on the char ":" format is ...@HOSTNAME:PORT:SID

Comment: I've done this already (looked into metadata and parsing the url). But the URL in our case is a bit more complicated and changes often. e.g. jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION_LIST=(DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=10)(RETRY_COUNT=3)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST= xyz1.abc.de)(PORT=6778)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=Service2.oracle.db.de)))(DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=60)(RETRY_COUNT=1)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=xyz2.abc.de)(PORT=6777)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=Service2.oracle.db.de))))  I parsed this sort of url and the type you mentioned.

Comment: There could be more than two servers and i want to find out, to which im actually connected, which i can't from the url. Maybe there is a system table or a function which provides this information. I'm not a oracle specialist and want to know if there is a possibility to get this information.

Comment: seems that the "pool of connection" like is managed on the db itself. In this context a direct query like the one specified by tbone below would be a solution, assuming the db instance is available and answer to the query, which obviously defeat your purpose if don't get an answer to identify which db instance is failing. I'll look around and see if there is a way to do it differently with the jdbc driver.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the host name of the instance you're running from:

`select host_name from v$instance`

Comment: Doesn't work for me:  An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
select host_name from v$instance
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist [SQL State=42000, DB Errorcode=942]

Comment: Do you get this error if you run this query in sqlplus as well?

Comment: To run this query you need dba rights. Then it should work in my JDBC tool as well. But we decided to show the service name from 'select * from global_name' which should be unique in our network. +1 for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

try one of:

```
select sys_context('userenv','instance_name') from dual;
select sys_context('userenv','instance') from dual;
select sys_context('userenv','server_host') from dual;
```

Documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions165.htm